# How to tell if tinyMCE has been initated?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I initiate the tinyMCE like this in multiple tabs of JQuery:Tab. But I find to init tinyMCE multiple times yields readonly text areas. Thus I wish to check if tinyMCE is already initated. Is there a method like isInitated() or something similarly convenient there?

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "simple",
    width : "500",
    height : "300"
});
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I know this question is old, but...in case someone is still looking for the holy grail:

in tinymce 4, you can pass a callback to tinyMCE.init like so:

```
tinyMCE.init({
  //your regular parameters here...
  setup: function(editor) {
    editor.on('init', function() {
      //all your after init logics here.
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: "This option enables you to add events to editor instances before they get rendered."- http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:setup. So it cannot help you to find whether  tinyMCE is already initiated, right ?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on why you care about if tinyMCE is initialized. If you wanna do something only after it is initialized, you want to use callbacks; if you only wanna know if tinyMCE is initialized on a specific element, you may wanna use `tinyMCE.get('#id')` instead. Or you can always set a flag of something in the tinyMCE init callback so you can check that flag in other places.

Comment: Strange... Oficial code http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onInit doesn't work, `editor.on('init', function() {... `works. Thanks!

Comment: @Chaki_Black 2 years later... You were referencing API version 3 but probably using tinyMCE version 4. So [official code works](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:event.tinymce.Editor.init)

Answer (score 27):

You can use `tinymce.editors.length` to see if there is already an editor instance initalized (`tinymce.editors.length > 0`).

Answer (score 4):

You can add `init_instance_callback` to `init()` parameters. This callback will be invoked when the tinymce instance is already inited.

Answer (score 3):

To check if "tinyMCE" is set just use this:

```
if(typeof(tinyMCE) != "undefined") {}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using tincyMCE 4.7.2 
I tried the answer of @Thariama and it did not work for me, I guess because his answer is valid for the older versions of the tinyMCE.

here is what worked for me (again, according to the version you are working on, this could not be helpful for you)

```
if (tinymce.initialized === true)
```

Comment: Not working for me, but this setting exists https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/ so I use tinymce.get('my_editor_id').initialized

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (typeof(tinymce.activeEditor.contentDocument) !== "undefined") {
 // initialized
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found other solution for this.

Let's say that You've got element

```
<textarea id="tinymce0"></textarea>
```

Now let's say that You initialize it:

```
let config  = { selector : '#tinymce0'};
tinymce.init(config);
```

After that You can make this:

```
let tinmyMceInstance = tinymce.get('tinymce0');
if( tinmyMceInstance === null ){
  // Your code if not initialized
}
```

Keep in mind:

- this works only with id, seems like using **classname** for `get()` won't work

Works in:

```
{
     releaseDate: "2019-05-09",
     majorVersion: "5",
     minorVersion: "0.5",
}
```

So it's probably: **5.5**

Answer (score -1):

To do Thariama's solution in TinyMCE 6 onwards, you can make a check like this:

```js
if (tinymce.Editor.length > 0) {
    // your action here
}
```